# Any alternatives to this for loop to make more efficient my code? It is taking several hours to run

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python, so I'm wondering if there is a way to make more efficient my code.

I am analyzing a dataframe that has 800 columns and 252 rows. I am analyzing each column's difference to the 799 remaining columns throughout the 252 rows, then I add up all the squared differences and store that value in a new dataframe. The result is a dataframe (symmetric matrix) that is 800x800 showing the summed squared differences throughout the 252 rows among each possible pair of columns in the dataset.

The issue is that the code took 5 hours to run, so I wanted to know if any of you have any suggestions on how to make it more efficient or maybe there is a built up function alreay? the .cov() function performs somewhat similar calculations and it takes only a few seconds to run on the same dataset so there must be a way to improve my code, which you can find below:

```
sqdiff_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns, index=df.columns)
# filling up the empty dataframe with the squared differences.
for c in sqdiff_df.columns:
    for i in sqdiff_df.index:
        ticker_c_normalisedP = year1_normalized_p[c]
        ticker_i_normalisedP = year1_normalized_p[i]
        sqdiff_ic = (year1_normalized_p.eval("@ticker_c_normalisedP - @ticker_i_normalisedP")**2).sum()
        sqdiff_df.loc[i,c] = sqdiff_ic
```

Comment: The `eval` is a huge red flag there. That's invoking a Python parser at *every* loop iteration.

Comment: What is "year1_normalized_p"?

Comment: "df" is a dataframe with the normal values I am using to calculate the squared differences. But I converted those values from "df" to base 1 so that they are comparable to each other, technically "year1_normalized_p" are the values rom "df" but normalized.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo thanks for your input, that decreased the time dramatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `sqdiff_ic = ((ticker_c_normalisedP - ticker_i_normalisedP)**2).sum()`. The `eval` will be extremely slow.